# Yisrael or Yaakov?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, avot-patriarch-fathers

Does anyone have any sources on a conclusive guide to when the name "Yisrael" is used and when the name "Yaakov" is used in the Torah in reference to Yaakov Avinu, the individual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Here: http://www.aish.com/tp/i/moha/48955486.html

The Main Points:

> Rashi [7] suggests that the name
>   Yaakov indicates subservience, while
>   the name Yisrael indicates strength
>   and victory. Varying uses reflect
>   different aspects of Yaakov's
>   personality that come to light in
>   varying situations. Another view is
>   offered by Meshech Chochma, who sees
>   the different names as expressing the
>   distinction between Yaakov as an
>   individual versus Yisrael as a
>   national identity. Thus, according to
>   Meshech Chochma, God addresses
>   "Yisrael" exclusively when, and only
>   when, there are national issues at
>   hand. [8]
>
> The Netziv [9] proposes that the
>   distinction is between a supernatural
>   aspect (Yisrael), versus a more
>   mundane name (Yaakov) used when
>   natural events or actions are
>   described. Because humans cannot
>   function purely on the spiritual
>   plane, both names are needed.
>
> Each of these suggestions seems to
>   point to an unresolved tension in
>   Yaakov's life which results in a dual
>   identity.
>
> [7] Rashi Bereishit 35:10, this idea
>   is echoed by Rabbenu Bachya 32:29.
>
> [8] Meshech Chochma Bereishit 35:10.
>
> [9] Ha'amek Davar Bereishit 35:10, see
>   Rabenu Bachaya 47:29 who see Yaakov as
>   a name indicating physicality, and
>   Yisrael as a name indicative of the
>   spiritual.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw a commentary on the verse from the Book of Numbers

> lo hibit aven b'Yaakov v'lo ra'ah amal b'Yisrael...

which says that Yaakov refers to the *guf* (body), and Yisrael refers to the *neshama* (soul).

Unfortunately I cannot remember where I saw it.